# Information schema process list and updating state

Tags: mysql, updating, records, del

Well here is my question, I messed up yesterday and made a delete query on my database. The messing up is not the delete part, but the fact that i didnt realized it was 424 million records. I keeping track on the query with the information schema but i would like to know what the "updating" state stands by. What is it doing right now, deleting or what?

Here is the get

"COMMAND": Query
"STATE": "updating"
"INFO": "delete from posicion where fechahora between '2012-12-12 00:00:00' and '2014-12-15 00:00:00'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your delete query is still running.

You can double check this by issuing this  command, from some other client besides the one from which you issued the delete query.

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

This will show your active processes and what they are doing. Your DELETE query may be among them.

If you

1. don't want to delete those rows.
2. are using InnoDB for your `posicion` table, and
3. have not yet finished running the DELETE query

you can look at the processlist to get the id of your delete operation, then issue the command

```
KILL QUERY id
```

InnoDB should roll back the in-progress delete and leave your table as it was before you started the `DELETE` .

Good luck!

Comment: Well I was not looking to rollback the delete but its nice to know either way. XD